# Error in wilcox.test.formula grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I want to do Mann-Whitney test in R. But the program gives me an error:

> Error in wilcox.test.formula(SLR0115_1_9_$Worm_Names ~ SLR0115_1_9_$CTWF,  : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

my data is two columns: one of them is a factor and the second - values.
this is the head of my data:

```
head(SLR0115_1_9_)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Worm_Names   CTWF
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 1red        9986.
2 1red       18628.
3 1red       17348.
4 1red       24217.
5 1red       22296.
6 1red       22845.
```

that`s what I am trying:

```
wilcox.test(SLR0115_1_9_$Worm_Names~SLR0115_1_9_$CTWF, correct=FALSE, exact=FALSE)
```

and it always gives me an error.

If somebody can help me understand what's wrong with my data or with code?

Comment: Can you produce a `dput(SLR0115_1_9_)` so we can try replicate your error?

Comment: The format for the formula is "y ~x" so if you try `wilcox.test(SLR0115_1_9_$CTWF ~ SLR0115_1_9_$Worm_Names, correct=FALSE, exact=FALSE)` it should work.

Comment: @Dave2e thank you! it was so simple!